# New project in androidStudio makes many folders and a plugin errors. even after Reinstallation

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

In android studio when I create a new project, every time it makes many folders inside one another. I have every required sdk downloaded but even though it is giving an error "Install missing platform(s) and sync projects". Even after re-installation of android studio I'm facing the same issue. :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to File > settings > Appearance & Behavior > Android Sdk > under SDK platform, select the missing platform  and apply.

If that doesn't fix it, go to the root folder of the project, remove the build folder from there.Then click on the app folder, and remove the build folder from there as well, and restart Studio.

If that also, doesnt fix the issue, update your gradle-wrapperproperties file under gradle scripts.

You can also downgrade the build tool version of your application from the gradle file. That will also fix the issue. However , it would be good practice to update it to latest.

let me know the result.